# unknown type name C vs C++

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

I tried to create a struct that holds a  pointer to it's type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test{
    test* t;
};
 int main(){
    return 0;
 }
```

while compiled with gcc, this code produced an error:

> :5:2: error: unknown type name 'test'

but while compiled on g++ it went just fine.

So what I want to understand is:

**1)** What causes this difference? I thought that if gcc uses one-pass compilation and g++ uses multipass that could explain it, but as I understood, this is not true.

**2)** How can I avoid this error and define a struct with a pointer to it's own type? (I don't want to use a void* or use casting unless there is no other option)

Comment: Try: struct test * t; as struct variable.

Comment: @Viatorus tried that, but when dereferencing that afterwards I got "incomplete type" error

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: C and C++ are different but related languages, and you should have no expectation that a C++ program is also a valid C program, although the opposite is usually true.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please choose one tag, which is appropriate for your question.

Comment: @CiaPan OP actually ask for the difference between these languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write struct before test* t to define a pointer to our struct:

```
struct test* t;
```

That is one different between C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect in "C". You have to use `struct <structname>* <varname>;` in format.

In c++, you can omit the "struct" in front of it. In C however, you have to write it to define a pointer to your struct.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct test{
   struct test* t;
} test;
 int main(){
    return 0;
 }
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/Pq6Po9)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `typedef` `struct test` `test` `;` before you can use it in that way.

This should work just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test{
   struct test* t;
};
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct test test;
struct test{
   test* t;
};
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem is gcc is a C compiler and takes types literally. 
If you use a c++ compiler, it may not care. c++ simplifies the types for you C does not.
Be careful of this fact.
C code will compile in a c++ compiler but c++ will not compile in a c compiler.

Comment: "*C code will compile in a c++ compiler*" - most C code isn't valid C++.

Comment: It depends if you are using strict mode or not. Depending on the c++ compiler to ensure backwards compatibility the compiler will just do it.